# My site Cache version problem

Tags: fetch-as-google, google-cache

I have an issue for last month and that also affected my website ranking. When I fetch my site it will be normal but after 48 hours it will be shown without title and description and this wording showing " Index of / .ftpquota .qidb/ · New folder.zip · wp-config.php. Apache Server at [smmpoint.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDgRL.png) Port 80" instead of description . please check in following image

[image]

Comment: *When I fetch my site*... How? This may help to clarify the situation. As well, are there other factors you can think of? Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are not uploading the data to the correct DocumentRoot. Make sure you are uploading the data under the public_html directory.

Also, make sure the domain name is not pointing to a subfolder of the root domain name..

Comment: It is quite common that people deploy their site to the wrong directory. My concern is that the OP says *When I fetch my site...* and I do not know what that means. It may be that the site works the way it should for a period then goes wonky. I have never seen this of course. Something to consider. I posted a comment for the OP asking for more specifics. Cheers!!